# Result depends on order of list even though it should not

Tags: haskell

I am spending a little time on Haskell in my holidays, but now I've run into a problem. I have a list which consists of booleans, and I am trying to make a function which takes a list of integers and flips the booleans at the corresponding positions.

If you load the following piece of code into GHCi and try to run **flipBits testBoard [1,0,2]** the result is *[True, True, False, False]*. If you run it with **flipBits testBoard [1,2,0]** the result is *[True, True, True, False]*.

I would like the result not to be dependent on the order of the numbers in the list passed to flipBits (apparently a 0 in the list stops the execution). What am I doing wrong?

```
flipBit board which (x:xs)
    | which == 0 = (not (board !! which)):xs
    | otherwise =  x:(flipBit board (which-1) xs)

flipBits board [] = board
flipBits board (x:xs) = flipBits (flipBit board x board) xs

testBoard = take 4 $ repeat False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `flipBit` function

```
flipBit board which (x:xs)
    | which == 0 = (not (board !! which)):xs
    | otherwise =  x:(flipBit board (which-1) xs)
```

You replace all elements of the `board` that you want to flip with `not (board !! 0)`, since the only flipping is when `which` reaches 0.

You simply want to remove one argument from that,

```
flipBit which (x:xs)
    | which == 0 = not x : xs
    | otherwise  = x : flipBit (which - 1) xs
```

and then have

```
flipBits board (x:xs) = flipBits (flipBit x board) xs
```

or, since that is a recurring pattern of application, use the appropriate higher order function,

```
flipBits board ixs = foldr flipBit board ixs
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a blunder from my side. Also thank you for the foldr comment, I'm still in the beginning of learning about folds so I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    | which == 0 = (not (board !! which)):xs
```

The guard says that the RHS is only going to be evaluated when `which` is 0, so this is the same as

```
    | which == 0 = (not (board !! 0)):xs
```

`board` here is the "original" board, before we started walking along it. So instead of flipping the bit at a certain position, the bit is replaced by the inverse of the bit at the head of the list.

You should instead do

```
    | which == 0 = not x : xs
```

and then ask yourself why you need the first parameter to `flipBit`.